# Cannot perform an aggregate function on a subquery

Tags: t-sql, subquery, aggregate

Can someone help me with this query?

```
SELECT p.OwnerName, SUM(ru.MonthlyRent) AS PotentinalRent,  SUM(
    (SELECT COUNT(t.ID) * ru.MonthlyRent FROM tblTenant t 
      WHERE t.UnitID = ru.ID)
    ) AS ExpectedRent
 FROM tblRentalUnit ru
LEFT JOIN tblProperty p ON p.ID = ru.PropertyID
GROUP BY p.OwnerName
```

I'm having problems with the second sum, it won't let me do it. Evidently SUM won't work on subqueries, but I need to calculate the expected rent (MonthlyRent if there is a tenant assigned to the RentalUnit's id, 0 of they're not). How can I make this work?

Comment: I even run a search to be sure ... There is no third SUM :-)

Comment: What is the meaning of the the product of the rental Unit's Monthly rent times the number of tenants in that unit?  You're not going to collect the full rent from each tenant in the unit are you?

Comment: there's only one tenant per unit, max.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.OwnerName, SUM(ru.MonthlyRent) AS PotentialRent, SUM(cnt) AS ExpectedRent
FROM    tblRentalUnit ru
LEFT JOIN
        tblProperty p
ON      p.ID = ru.PropertyID
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(t.id) * ru.MonthlyRent AS cnt
        FROM    tblTenant t
        WHERE   t.UnitID = ru.ID
        ) td
GROUP BY p.OwnerName
```

Here's a test script to check:

```
WITH    tblRentalUnit AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS id, 100 AS MonthlyRent, 1 AS PropertyID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id, 300 AS MonthlyRent, 2 AS PropertyID
        ),
        tblProperty AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS id, 'Owner 1' AS OwnerName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id, 'Owner 2' AS OwnerName
        ),
        tblTenant AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS id, 1 AS UnitID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id, 1 AS UnitID
        )
SELECT  p.OwnerName, SUM(ru.MonthlyRent) AS PotentialRent, SUM(cnt) AS ExpectedRent
FROM    tblRentalUnit ru
LEFT JOIN
        tblProperty p
ON      p.ID = ru.PropertyID
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(t.id) * ru.MonthlyRent AS cnt
        FROM    tblTenant t
        WHERE   t.UnitID = ru.ID
        ) td
GROUP BY p.OwnerName
```

Comment: ru.MontlyRent can't be used there.

Comment: It's like an outer join, with the difference that it uses an inner query instead of a subquery.

Comment: This means that the query results are "applied" to each record from the outer query. It's like a `SELECT` clause subquery but can return multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

What is the meaning of the sum of the unitMonthlyRent times the number of tenants, for some partiicular rental unit (`COUNT(t.ID) * ru.MonthlyRent` )?

Is it the case that all you are trying to do is see the difference between the total potential rent from all untis versus the expected rent (From only occcupied units) ? If so, then try this

```
Select p.OwnerName, 
   Sum(r.MonthlyRent) AS PotentinalRent,  
   Sum(Case t.Id When Null Then 0 
         Else r.MonthlyRent End) ExpectedRent
From tblRentalUnit r
    Left Join tblTenant t 
      On t.UnitID = r.ID
    left Join tblProperty p
       On p.ID = r.PropertyID)
Group By p.OwnerName
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. r.PropertyID in the left join isn't even in scope.

Comment: Yes, See that now, the join should be to rental unit in your schema